# Double summation with dependent variables

Tags: summation

Currently i have taken part in a coding contest where i was asked this question https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc186/tasks/abc186_d. In the editorial solution they have given something like this:

[image]

Here especially in the second last step how the outer summation changes from $\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}$ to $\sum_{i=1}^N$ and the inner changes from $\sum_{j=i+1}^N$ to $\sum_{j=1}^N$?

I am not able understand this double summation variable change. Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity write $x_{ij}:=|A_i-A_j|$. Work backwards. The final quantity is
$$\frac12\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N x_{ij}$$
which is a sum over all pairs $(i,j)$ where $i$ and $j$ each run from $1$ to $N$. The trick is to observe that this sum can be broken into three pieces:
$$\frac12\sum_{i<j} x_{ij} + \frac12\sum_{i=j}x_{ij} + \frac12\sum_{i>j}x_{ij}.$$
By symmetry, the first and last sums are equal to each other (since $x_{ij}=x_{ji}$). Meanwhile, the middle sum equals zero (since $x_{ii}=0$). So now the sum is
$$
\sum_{i<j}x_{ij}
$$
which is the first quantity. If you plot in the $i,j$-plane all possible values for the pairs $(i,j)$ you'll get a square array of dots. The above maneuver corresponds to splitting the square into a diagonal (where $i=j$), and two triangles with the same $x_{ij}$ values.

---

EDIT: To go from the second-last line to the last line, the steps in detail are:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^N (x_{ij} + x_{ji})\\
\stackrel{(1)}=&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^N x_{ij} + \frac12\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^Nx_{ji}\\
\stackrel{(2)}=&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^N x_{ij} + \frac12\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\sum_{i=j+1}^Nx_{ij}\\
\stackrel{(3)}=&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^N x_{ij}+\frac12\sum_{i=1}^N x_{ii} + \frac12\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}\sum_{i=j+1}^Nx_{ij}\\
\stackrel{(4)}=&\frac12\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N x_{ij}
\end{aligned}
$$
In step (1) we split the sum into two pieces. In step (2) we reindex the second sum by relabeling index $i$ as $j$ and index $j$ as $i$. In step (3) we are adding zero. In step (4) we observe that the three summations cover all possible pairs of $(i,j)$ from $1$ to $N$.

Comment: Thanks for your time @grand_chat but I want to know how can we derive the final result from the given initial summation of ∑N−1i=1 to ∑Ni=1 , ∑Nj=i+1 to ∑Nj=1 to the given result 12∑i=1N∑j=1Nxij , because I want to know if there is any general method for these kind of questions as these types of questions are asked quite frequently ? So if you can suggest any general method or formula for how to approach such questions it will be very helpful for me and again thanks for answering.